# Retrieving Data from a Node JS module and passing it to Backbone View

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js

I am new to both Node JS and Backbone.

Able to retrieve data from NodeJS's Bitcoin. I am able to send it to the browser. 
 How can I send it to a Backbone View or Model?
Is it possible?
**Node JS code:**

```
var http = require('http'),
    express = require('express'),
    bitcoin = require('bitcoin');

var app = express();
app.listen(3000);
var client = new bitcoin.Client({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8332,
    user: 'himanshuy',
    pass: 'xxxx'
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
   res.send('Hello World');
});

app.get('/getDifficulty', function(req, res){
    client.getDifficulty(function(err, difficulty) {
        if(err) {
            res.send('Bitcoin error: ' + err);
        } else {
            res.send('Difficulty: ' + difficulty);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Backbone is a client side library, so you need to do it on the client and it would be good to show some client js that you have.

Comment: Presently I don'have it. Stuck with the idea that how Backbone model will `get` this NodeJS data. What will be the url value for the model?

Comment: You need to do a Backbone tutorial. You don't know enough about what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have completed few tutorial. As I said I am new to it. If you are getting my problem please help to find the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at

- http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-model/
- http://dailyjs.com/2011/04/04/node-tutorial-19/
- http://backbonetutorials.com/nodejs-restify-mongodb-mongoose/

which cover the basics you're asking for.